# ImportError: cannot import name flib

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, pymc

I want to use Python for trying out hddm.

I installed anaconda, Python 2.7. When I try to follow the hddm tutorial in the command line window in spyder, the following happens, which seems to be a problem in pymc:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
import hddm

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-17365318b31c>", line 1, in <module>
    import hddm

  File "/Users/c/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hddm/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import likelihoods

  File "/Users/c/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hddm/likelihoods.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymc as pm

  File "/Users/c/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .distributions import *

  File "/Users/c/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/distributions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import flib, utils

ImportError: cannot import name flib
```

I work on Mac OS X 10.7. On the web, I find some comments concerning pymc possibly not being compiled with the correct version of gfortran, but the solutions all seem to be for windows. Also, I thought that this kind of problem should not happen with an integrated system like Anaconda?

Comment: is pymc included in Anaconda or did you have to install it?

Comment: Dear Padraic, thanks for your response! It comes with Anaconda.

Comment: if you import pymc and run pymc.__version__ what does it show?

Comment: well essentially the same(sorry for the bad formatting …):

    import pymc
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-35-5f262cfcb99b>", line 1, in <module>
    import pymc

    File "/Users/cfiebach/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .distributions import *

    File "/Users/cfiebach/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/distributions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import flib, utils 

    ImportError: cannot import name flib

Comment: been quite a while since I used anaconda but can you try using pip to upgrade the pymc package?  `pip install -U  pymc`

Comment: Not working, I just paste some of the last lines: ...  



  File "/Users/c/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 418, in customize_compiler

    _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)

  File "/Users/c/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler

    "Cannot locate working compiler")

SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler

----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of pymc
Cleaning up...

Comment: try installing gfortran and then using pip again https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS or conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/pymc pymc

Comment: This solved it! Thanks a lot Padraic. The conda command needed to be slightly modified so that it worked: conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/pymc pymc   --- Thanks again, this was really great help!!!

Comment: If you have figured out a solution, please post it as an answer instead of editing your title and placing the words "Solved" in it.

Comment: @Makoto, I will add the answer

Comment: I can't upload the answer at present ...

Comment: @p_HD, it is ok I added the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. use `conda install -c conda.binstar.org/pymc pymc`
2. install [gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS) and use `pip install -U pymc`