# Failure to import PyMC (gfortran library not loaded after installing from conda.binstar)

Tags: homebrew, anaconda, pymc, conda

I am running Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.0.1 (x86_64) and conda 3.5.5
on Mac OS 10.9.4 (Maverick)

I installed PyMC by running

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/pymc pymc`

However, `import pymc`gave an error (I copy the Traceback at the end).

*Edit1*: from reading this question ["cannot import name flib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480279/importerror-cannot-import-name-flib?rq=1), it seems to me the issue is that by installing PyMC with anaconda it is built against a different gfortran, not the one supplied by `brew install gcc`. I'm happy to uninstall things and try again, but I hope somebody will provide me with instructions before I screw up things more!

*Edit2*: The Traceback tells me that `//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/flib.so`is trying to call `/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib`, which doesn't exist. I think until recently `homebrew` installed gfortran on it's own and hence would have a folder in `/usr/local/Cellar`. Now, however, `gfortran`is in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1/bin` when it is installed by `brew install gcc`. Help!

---

(*Aside*:
Since the error suggests a problem with the gfortran compiler I installed from `brew`, let me give you some details on that, though the might not be relevant.

I installed `gfortran` from brew by calling

`brew install gcc`

It threw some error and suggested I link gmp, mpfr, libmpc, isl and cloog. Hence I did

`brew link gmp` (and mpfr, etc.)

Just in case, `which gfortran` gives

`/usr/local/bin/gfortran`

---

Here is the traceback for `import pymc`:

```
In [1]: import pymc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5f262cfcb99b> in <module>()
----> 1 import pymc

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/__init__.pyc in <module>()
     28 from .PyMCObjects import *
     29 from .InstantiationDecorators import *
---> 30 from .CommonDeterministics import *
     31 from .NumpyDeterministics import *
     32 from .distributions import *

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py in <module>()
     19 import inspect
     20 import types
---> 21 from .utils import safe_len, stukel_logit, stukel_invlogit, logit, invlogit, value, find_element
     22 from copy import copy
     23 import sys

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/utils.py in <module>()
     12 from copy import copy
     13 from .PyMCObjects import Variable
---> 14 from . import flib
     15 import pdb
     16 from numpy.linalg.linalg import LinAlgError

ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/flib.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/flib.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: You should make sure the old gfortran formula isn't installed with brew rm gfortran and making sure /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran is empty. Then, I'd try rebuilding pymc. Did this ever work or is this a new problem?

Comment: Hi. I had PyMC working on a different computer and most likely a previous version of homebrew.
I did `brew rm gfortran` and `/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran`is empty. I still get the same error when installing with `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/pymc pymc`.

Comment: Oh; this binary distribution is broken. Don't use it. If you run otool -L flib.so you'll see that it's linked to a hard-coded path that you don't and shouldn't have. Install pymc with pip?

Comment: I tried `pip install pymc` and throws a different error:

    `ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o`

    `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: This looks like a setuptools bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868897/library-not-found-for-lbundle1-o-when-installing-python-packages-ffnet-spacep -- the workaround seems to be making sure you have the Xcode Command Line Tools (separate from Xcode proper) installed, which you can do with `xcode-select --install`, if you don't already have them.

Comment: @TimSmith, thanks a lot for following up on this. It seems the PyMC developer have an issue with this (see [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/556) ). I did try `xcode-select --install` but it didn't help. I'll try more things tomorrow and report back in case I get lucky.

Comment: See https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/556

Comment: You macOS guys have it easy :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is far from a complete answer, but the following worked, at least with the `gfortran` compiler installed from `brew install gcc`. It might work with a different compiler or even without one at all, so try installing it this way:

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/tobeplugged pymc`

Also, check the updates in the PyMC developers Github page [in issue 556](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/556)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to install pymc to work with a virtualenv deployment of python. I solved it using two steps. First, I did not have the correct gcc library. I solved this using homebrew:

```
brew install gfortran
```

Next, my previous install of pymc was trying to link to a version of fortran located here:

```
/4.9.1/libgfortran.3.dyli
```

when homebrew by default places it here:

```
/4.9/libgfortran.3.dyli
```

So I solved this by cycling my pymc deployment:

```
.../bin/pip uninstall pymc  
.../bin/pip install --upgrade pip
.../bin/pip install pymc
```

This cases pip and pymc to work together to find your recently install fortran library. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but these are the steps that worked for me as a homebrew user on OS X Sierra

The main point is that for pymc to build it needs gfortran 4.2 as provided by the apple-gcc42 package. It is only a dependency at buildtime, so you can undo these changes after the pip install completes.

```
brew install python3
brew install apple-gcc42
brew unlink gcc
ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gfortran-4.2 /usr/local/bin/gfortran

#optional: create virtualenv
python3 -mvenv ~/venvs/my_venv
source ~/venvs/my_venv/bin/activate
#end optional

pip3 install numpy
pip3 install pymc

# restore gcc
rm /usr/local/bin/gfortran
brew link gcc
```

Comment: The point of unlinking and linking is that `pymc` needs a specific gfortran version for building/compiling, but then using it doesn't need it? (maybe you can add that info to your answer)